# Operating System Semaphores

Tags: kernel, system, mutex, semaphore

I have looked all around and can't seem to find the answer to my questions. I've been trying to wrap my head around semaphores and where they are actually implemented. I understand that semaphores are an operating system feature but can also be used in an application level program. My question is, why is there a need to use semaphores in applications when the operating system (I thought) is supposed to take care of access issues?

Answer (score 2):

A semaphore is a variable or **abstract data type** that is used for controlling access, by multiple processes, to a common resource in a concurrent system such as a multiprogramming operating system.

A useful way to think of a semaphore is as a record of how many units of a particular resource are available, coupled with operations to safely (i.e., without [race conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition)) adjust that record as units are required or become free, and, if necessary, wait until a unit of the resource becomes available. Semaphores are a useful tool in the prevention of race conditions;

[Courtesy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_(programming))

Answer (score 0):

An application is a set of processes, all executing different codes.

Lets say there are 2 processes - A and B in an appication .
A and B want to access a particular file - "play.txt"  in an alternate way . I mean A accesses first and then B and then A and so on.

Operating system has no idea about this order of execution. OS only knows about the kernel processes and that's why it has to be implemented by the user . User will use semaphores in his program which will be read by the OS to learn everything about the two processes .

Answer (score 0):

semaphore is a data type provided by the OS which is used for process synchronization.
semaphore has two atomic operations(atomic means either execute fully or not at all)wait and signal.during these two operations context switch does not take place since they are atomic.
Programmer has to implement these operations so that OS does not context switch during some important operation.
for example-reader writer problem.

NOTE:-operating system is very complex ,OS concepts are ment to give us an idea of working of operating system.but current system working may very as with every decade there computer system upgrades with respect to OS as well as hardware.OS implements various concepts to keep it running and to provide better CPU utilization.

Answer (score 0):

A sempahore is used to guard access to a data structure shared between two of more independently-running threads or processes.  You may encounter the phrase "critical region" used in semaphore descriptions; ignore it.  You don't protect code with semaphore, you protect shared data structures.

Say you have these variables:

```
int savings;
int house_payment;
```

and you want to move some money from the savings bucket into the house_payment bucket.  While this is going on, another process needs to know your bank balance and loan balance.

Process A takes the payment, subtracting the value from savings.
Process A then adds the value to the house_payment bucket.

Now suppose process B needs to check the load balance and your savings balance.  Since the processes are not synchronized, process B looks at the values at the time process A has removed money from your savings, but before process A can add the payment to your house_payment.

As far as process B is concerned, the savings bucket has too little money and the house_payment bucket does not have enough.  Your house payment money is lost in transit.  If process B then looks again, magically the missing money appears in the house_payment bucket.

To protect against that window, a semaphore is used.  Process A takes the semaphore while transferring the money and releases the semaphore after the money is placed into the house_payment bucket.

Process B takes the semaphore before accessing the savings and house_payment buckets, and releases the semaphore when done.

With a semaphore guarding accesses to the shared data, neither process will see the inconsistent state caused by checking the buckets while the money is in transit.

Now, the operating system *cannot* know when to apply the semaphore guard.  This is something the application must manage.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, operating system is supposed to take care of access issues and semaphores just helps it to do that. 
Try to understand it this way: 
There's a railroad and there are 4 trains(say, train A,B,C,D) waiting to access the railroad. Now, the condition is, only one train can access it at a given instance. So, what the station master does, is give each driver of the train a bulb. If the bulb of train(say, train A) is on, that means, train A has the permission to use the railroad. While A is using the road, train B,C,D will wait(in the waiting queue) with their bulbs turned off.
The protocol is, once train A is done using the road, it turns its bulb off and the next train in the queue(say, train B), gets its bulb turned on and uses the road. This goes on till all the trains in the queue get a chance.

The *bulbs are the semaphores* in this case, the *trains are the processes/job*s, and the *railroad is the critical section*(shared resource).